# Error in mapper and reducer with python

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, amazon-s3, mapreduce

There is a problem in the mapper.py file when I run it in the cluster. The error is " unexpected syntax before line" in "strl = line.strip()".
There is no error when I test it locally. I want to get the words of text file stored and change their format and count them and send to the output in s3 bucket.

Guidance most welcome. Thanks

mapper:

```
import sys, re

for line in sys.stdin:
strl = line.strip()
words = strl.split()
for word in words:
    word = word.lower()
    result = ""
    charref = re.compile("[a-f]")
    match = charref.search(word[0])
    if match:
        result+= "TR2234J"
    else:
        result+= ""
    print result, "\t"
```

reducer:

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    new_word =""
    words = line.split("\t")
    final_count = len(words)
    my_num = final_count / 6
    for i in range (my_num):
        new_word = "".join(words[i*6:10+(i*6)])
        print new_word, "\t"
```

Comment: Is that the actual indentation?

Comment: I don't think so When I test it locally there is no error. I use python 2.7 on windows. I think when I write the code on windows then upload it on S3 something goes wrong.